# Does SDWebImage employ both memory caching and disk caching (when needed)? If not, how should I handle this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdwebimage, nscache

My app deals with a lot of image downloads, and as such I want it to be as fast as possible for the user. Preferably, when the image downloads, it should never have to be downloaded again.

My initial strategy was to save all the `UIImages` in an `NSArray`, but eventually this would consume a ton of memory/RAM.

I then thought of using `NSCache`, which automatically removes items if memory usage gets too high. My issue with this is that once it removes the item, I'd have to redownload the image the next time I need it.

It seems my best solution would be (and if I'm totally missing something better, please tell me) to save them in an `NSCache` style solution and when `NSCache` goes to remove an item, save it to disk. Therefore, when it needs it the next time it won't need to redownload it, even if the cache removed it, and it will still be faster fetching it from the disk than from the server again.

I'm curious if libraries like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) – which I understand uses a cache so images aren't downloaded multiple times – use such a solution, or are they more like `NSCache` where the image will simply be gone when memory usage is too high, and a redownload would be necessary. (Only, once the app finishes executing I wouldn't want it to stay on disk any longer.)

Am I looking at this totally wrong? Should I be doing something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

SDWebImage saves to both cache and disk by default. It can also be configured to your liking if you want only memory storage or only disk storage etc. In my experience it is the best async image downloading framework out there.